# Group and sort array in Javascript

Tags: javascript, angularjs, arrays

I have the following variable:

```
var myArray = [
  {name: "Alf", "type": "Phone"},
  {name: "John", "type": "Web"},
  {name: "Peter", "type": "Email"},
  {name: "Louise", "type": "Phone"},
  {name: "Jenny", "type": "Email"},
  {name: "Fred", "type": "Web"}
]
```

I would like to group it by type and in a specific order: first all the "Web", then all the "Email", then all the "Phone", as per below:

```
  {name: "John", "type": "Web"},
  {name: "Fred", "type": "Web"},
  {name: "Peter", "type": "Email"},
  {name: "Jenny", "type": "Email"},
  {name: "Louise", "type": "Phone"},
  {name: "Alf", "type": "Phone"},
```

I tried the code below, which is grouping them but with no order.

```
var grouped = _(myArray)
          .groupBy('type')
          .flatten()
          .value();
```

How can I order those groups as needed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the standard [Array#sort](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort). However, since you want a specific object, you'll to assign a value for each type, and then use the values in the sort:

```js
/** assign a value for each type **/
var order = {
  "Web": 300,
  "Email": 200,
  "Phone": 100
};

var myArray = [
  {name: "Alf", "type": "Phone"},
  {name: "John", "type": "Web"},
  {name: "Peter", "type": "Email"},
  {name: "Louise", "type": "Phone"},
  {name: "Jenny", "type": "Email"},
  {name: "Fred", "type": "Web"}
];

myArray.sort(function(a, b) {
  // sort using the values
  return order[b.type] - order[a.type];
});

console.log(myArray);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use JavaScript's `Array.sort()` function, with a specific map containing the weights of the values:

```js
var myArray = [
  {name: "Alf", "type": "Phone"},
  {name: "John", "type": "Web"},
  {name: "Peter", "type": "Email"},
  {name: "Louise", "type": "Phone"},
  {name: "Jenny", "type": "Email"},
  {name: "Fred", "type": "Web"}
];
// could be any three primitives as long as p1 < p2 < p3, i.e: 'a', 'k', 'z'
var myMap = {"Web":0, "Email":1, "Phone":2};
myArray.sort(function(a, b) {
 return myMap[a.type] - myMap[b.type]; // sort by weights
});
console.log(myArray);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could sort with an object for the sort order and a default value for types, which have no known order.

```js
var array = [{ name: "last", type: "very last" }, { name: "Alf", type: "Phone" }, { name: "John", type: "Web" }, { name: "Peter", type: "Email" }, { name: "Louise", type: "Phone" }, { name: "Jenny", type: "Email" }, { name: "Fred", type: "Web" }],
    order = { Web: 1, Email: 2, Phone: 3 };

array.sort(function (a, b) {
    return (order[a.type] || Infinity) - (order[b.type] || Infinity);
});

console.log(array);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```